# "Compilation error" with function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why am I getting a compilation error here? The names of all the attributes of the table are correct. Also, the table exists.

```
SQL> create or replace function user_annual_comp(f_eno emp1.empno%type) return number
  2  is
  3    f_sal emp1.salary%type;
  4    f_comm emp1.comm%type;
  5    annual_comm number;
  6  begin
  7    select salary into f_sal from emp1 where empno = f_eno;
  8    select comm into f_comm from emp1 where empno = f_eno;
  9    if f_sal is null then
 10      f_sal := 0;
 11    end if;
 12    if f_comm is null then
 13      f_comm := 0;
 14    end if;
 15    annual_comm = (f_sal + f_comm) * 12;
 16    return annual_comm;
 17  end;
 18  /
```

Result:

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: No more specific info about the error message? Which line?

Comment: What does `show error` give you?

Comment: Hopefully OP compiled the function in `SQL*Plus` :-)

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator in PL/SQL is `:=`, while `=` is the equality comparison operator. Change line 15 to

```
annual_comm := (f_sal + f_comm) * 12;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You could write that entire function in simple SQL:

```
Select (nvl(sal,0) + nvl(comm,0))*12 as "annual_comm"
   From emp
  Where empno = input_emp_no;
```

Never use PL/SQL when the same could be done in plain SQL.

However, if you still insist to write a function, then the logic in the body could be rewritten as :

`annual_comm := (nvl(sal,0) + nvl(comm,0))*12`

And get rid of the `IF-END IF` block.